# I want to be able to filter the Stack Exchange front page to remove specific sites

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, hot-questions

The [front page](https://stackexchange.com/) contains hot questions from many sites.

However, some sites I am not interested in and I want to permanently blacklist them. Can this feature be added (unless it is already present, in which case please tell me how to use it)?

Note that I do *not* want to limit my attention to sites I already know about (i.e. subscription is not an answer).

For example, I am interested in Lisp. SE has several sites which have Lisp questions: StackOverflow, Emacs.SE, CodeReview.SE, Programmers.SE &c (not to mention all the platform-specific sites like Unix.SE and Apple.SE which also have Lisp-related questions). This means that white-listing is not an option.
However, there are now the Japanese-language Ja.SE and Portugese-language Pt.SE, and I understand neither and I don't want to ever see anything related to those sites. This makes black-listing imperative.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest thing to do is to use the [filtered questions](https://stackexchange.com/filters) part of Stack Exchange.

[image]

One of the default filters is that of "my sites" which is limited to just the sites you have accounts on.  Create accounts on all the sites that you want to have on the page, and delete ones that you don't.  This assumes that you don't mind creating or deleting your accounts.

[image]

Ok, so that was a bit heavy handed.  You could also do a whitelist of just the sites you want.  No, there is no blacklist.  It's a whitelist.  But its an easy to use whitelist.

[image]

Comment: Whitelist is no good because I have to update it all the time when new sites appear.